# Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ for the curve $x=1+t^2$, $y=t^3-3t$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Is this question simply asking me to find the first and second derivative for the two given equations?

I really don't know how to get started with this one and would appreciate any hints.

Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ for the curve $x=1+t^2$, $y=t^3-3t$

Comment: Hint: Can you find $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$? Then $dy/dx = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$

Comment: @Amzoti so $x=2t$ and $y=3t^2-3$?

Comment: No, $dx/dt = 2t$ and $dy/dt = 3t^2 -3$.

Comment: @Amzoti oh so you mean $\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$  for the $dx/dt$ and then do the same for the other one?

Comment: $x = t^2 \rightarrow dx = 2t ~dt \rightarrow \frac{dx}{dt} = 2t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see, you can simply substitute the two equations into each other s.t.
$$
y(x)=x^{1.5}-3\sqrt{x} 
$$
Else, as was mentioned before, simply consider
$$
\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{dy}{dx}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The second derivative is a little tricky, derive $\frac{dy}{dx}$ again with respect to t and divide this by $\frac{dx}{dt}$ which is $2t$. (and not 2 in case you wanted to derive the denom again!). Since I did not see anything about the second derivative posted by colleagues above, I thought I just mention it